# stripe capture charge doesn't process

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a webhook, that call this function when

event["type"] == "payment_intent.amount_capturable_updated"

```
def capture_order(session):
   ordered_uuid = uuid.UUID(session["metadata"]["pk_order"])

   try:
      order = Ordered.objects.filter(
        pk=ordered_uuid
    ).prefetch_related(
        "from_ordered", "from_ordered__to_product"
    ).get()
    except Ordered.DoesNotExist:
      stripe.PaymentIntent.cancel(session["id"])
    return HttpResponse(status=400)

   try:
      products = set()
      for ordered_product in order.from_ordered.all():
        product = ordered_product.to_product
        product.stock -= ordered_product.quantity
        if product.stock < 0:
            raise ValueError()
        products.add(product)
      with transaction.atomic():
        Product.objects.bulk_update(list(products), ("stock",))
        stripe.PaymentIntent.capture(session["id"])
   except ValueError:
    stripe.PaymentIntent.cancel(session["id"])
   except IntegrityError:
    stripe.PaymentIntent.cancel(session["id"])

   return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

and I get this error:

**This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of canceled. Only a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses may be captured: requires_capture.**

I had instantiate my checkout like this:

```
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price_data': {
                        'currency': 'eur',
                        'unit_amount_decimal': get_amount(self.object, with_delivery=True).quantize(TWO_PLACES),
                        'product_data': {
                            'name': f'Order #{self.object.pk}',
                        },
                    },
                    'quantity': 1,
                },
            ],
            payment_intent_data={
                "capture_method": "manual",
                "metadata": {
                    "pk_order": self.object.pk
                }
            })
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect your [dashboard logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) - I suspect that one of your error paths is canceling the payment intent before you try to capture it. You'll need to trace through your login to figure out why that's happening.